# triangular and square wave generator

Tags: generator, wave, function-generator, astable, multivibrator

the circuit below is a triangular and square wave generator.
With the first stage (the integrator) I can generate a triangular wave, and with the second stage (comparator) I can generate a triangular wave with a limited amplitude.

I've never seen this circuit with the net circled in red. What does this net does?
[image]

The text of the exercise says: Analyze the circuit assuming ideal op-amps.
...the circuit is an astable multivibrator in which zener diodes are ideal with Von =0,6V and Vbkd = 5.6V.
1)Describe the circuit and what kind of waveform can be found at Vout and Vs
2) find R1 and R2 in order to obtain an amplitude  of Vout of Vpeak = 10V, and f = 10kHz.

[image]

Comment: I expect the opamp (or comparator)  part numbers are the key to the answer.

Comment: For my opinion, R5 - together withe Z-diodes - constitutes a kind of output voltage stabilization at a fixed level. This makes sense  because it is this voltage which feeds the integrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right hand op-amp looks like a comparator (with an open collector output). The emitter I suspect is pin 1 and this is tied to -15 V. Open collector outputs require a pull-up resistor hence the need for R5 in your circuit.

If you could link where you found this circuit this could be confirmed. I think the comparator matches the pin out of the LM311: -

[image]

Collector = pin 7 and emitter = pin 1.

Comment: There's no link. This is a university exercise in which I have to find R1 and R2 under some conditions.
The operational amplifier are to be considered ideal, so there is no open collector output.

Comment: @FataMadrina No, you are probably wrong on this - it looks like it uses an LM311 comparator as the triangle to square generator. Of course if you use ideal op-amps then you don't need R5. Here's a link to plenty of circuits using two op-amps that might be useful: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=triangle+wave+generator&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW_MTpkIXQAhVEtxoKHTn3CiIQ_AUICSgC&biw=1149&bih=914

Comment: Edited with the full text translated (from italian). That net have to count in some way.

Comment: @FataMadrina I've explained what is happening. The original circuit uses a comparator (with a pin-out the same as the LM311) and they are asking you to assume the comparator is an ideal op-amp. So, omit R5 and proceed with the ideal op-amp solution.

Comment: Maybe you're right.

In a real circuit R5 is used as a pull-up resistor in order to have more current available at the comparator output?

Comment: The original circuit cannot work without R5 because a comparator like the LM311 needs a pull-up resistor because of the nature of its "floating" output transistor.